# Multilabel classification: Choosing threshold

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, multilabel-classification, generalization

I'm creating a multilabel classification approach based on sentence embeddings applied to text taken from a chatbot.
We have the following:

- a training dataset of 2,500 lines, where each line is a sentence associated with a particular label (the same sentence can end up with several labels)
- a production dataset made up of sentences taken from our previous chatbot version. Each sentence has been carefully annotated with the corresponding labels. (The number of labels per sentence ranges from 0 to 5 in most cases). There are about 1000 annotated sentences in this dataset.

I'd like to maximize the performance and generalizability of the approach, but I have the following limitations:

- the production dataset doesn't cover all possible labels, as some labels are rare but still important to detect
- the training dataset covers all labels, but has been created from imaginary sentences.

The current process is as follows:

- Evaluate performance with [MultilabelStratifiedKFold](https://github.com/trent-b/iterative-stratification) on the training dataset
- Select the best model and train the final model with all data
- Evaluate performance on the production dataset and choose a threshold to separate what the model considers relevant from the rest (for the moment, I'm choosing the point that balances micro averaged precision and micro averaged recall on the production dataset).

My question is this:
When you choose **the threshold**, how do you avoid overfitting as much as possible in this context? We don't want overfitting on either the training or production datasets.
Wouldn't optimizing the threshold on the production dataset bias the approach towards the labels available in the production dataset? In the same way, optimizing the threshold on the training dataset might bias the approach towards less "realistic" phrases from the real production context.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to validate your data properly. For example. Make sure that you have the same number of `labels` in train and validation set. Just in case if you don't know how to do it, use the following:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_dataset, validation_dataset = train_test_split(df, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 2023, stratify = df['target'])
```

This will create a valid dataset which can be used for validating your model. After that, you can use `StratifiedKFold` to make sure that it's not overfitting.

After using `StratifiedKFold`, you will have predictions on your `validation_data`. Keep that predictions and use them to choose your threshold value. While choosing a threshold value, use the following:

```py
def calculate_scores(y_true, y_probs):
    thresholds = np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)
    best_precision = 0
    best_threshold = 0

    for threshold in thresholds:
        y_pred = [1 if prob > threshold else 0 for prob in y_probs]
        precision = precision_score(y_true, y_pred)
       

        if precision > best_precision:
            best_precision = precision
            best_threshold = threshold

    return best_precision, best_threshold
```

This will give you the threshold value for the best precision score. And you can modify it with whichever metric that you are using.